# Python 3.4 - Numbers appended to a list are considered NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am making a program in which the user puts in some numbers, and then they can choose to calculate the mean, median, mode, or range of the numbers.

Here is my code.

```
import statistics

def number():
    yn = 'y'
    while yn == 'y':
        x = input("Enter a number.")
        numbers = []
        numbers.append(x)
        yn = input('Enter another one? y/n')
        if yn == 'n':
            break
            return numbers
def findaverage(x):
    x = sum(x)-len(x)
    print(x)
def findrange(x):
    x = max(x) - min(x)
    print(x)
def findmode(x):
    x = statistics.mode(x)
    print(x)
def findmedian(x):
    x = statistics.median(x)
    print(x)
def main():
    numbers = number()
    x = ''
    while x != "1" or x != "2" or x != "3" or x != "4":
        x = str(input("What would you like to do?\n1.Average\n2.Range\n3.Mode\n4.Median"))
        if x == "1":
            findaverage(numbers)
        elif x == "2":
            findrange(numbers)
        elif x == "3":
            findmode(numbers)
        elif x == "4":
            findmedian(numbers)


main()
```

When I run the program, it gives me the following traceback:

```
Enter a number.2
Enter another one? y/ny
Enter a number.4
Enter another one? y/ny
Enter a number.5
Enter another one? y/nn
What would you like to do?
1.Average
2.Range
3.Mode
4.Median1

File "C:\file.py", line 45, in <module>
  File , line 45, in <module>
    main()
    main()
  File , line 36, in main
  File , line 36, in main
    findaverage(numbers)
    findaverage(numbers)
  File , line 19, in findaverage
    x = sum(x)-len(x)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I am not sure what is causing this issue.

Help is appreciated, please, and thank you!

Comment: I have edited this question put back in the code causing the problem you asked about. Otherwise your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Feel free to ask another question to solve your other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues are:

- that you're resetting the list of numbers every time (`numbers = []`). Move that out of the loop.
- that you're breaking out of the loop before you're returning the list. Remove the `break` statement entirely.
- that you're getting strings from `input`, but your functions require Integers. Make that `x = int(input("Enter a number."))`.

Comment: I moved `numbers = []` out of the loop and it is now between `yn = 'y'` and `while yn == 'y':` but it still does that

Comment: Ah. I see. now remove the `break` statement.

Comment: Ah. `x = int(input("Enter a number."))`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that not all code paths through `number()` have an explicit `return` statement. When there is no explicit return, `None` is getting returned implicitly.